# How to get and compare the value results of a map<Integer, Integer>

Tags: java, hashmap

By calling a method ,at my case countInNumbers, is returning results as an array.

```
System.out.println(countIntInNumbers(Array));
```

result:

```
{1=17, 2=10, 3=16, 4=17, 5=13, 6=22, 7=10, 8=15, 9=16, 10=19, 11=11, 12=15, 13=16, 14=13, 15=19, 16=17, 17=13, 18=21, 19=19, 20=15,}
```

I  try to separate the numbers on different table depending their total value.
Example... I want to display the numbers that their total is between 3 and 4 to separate table than the other numbers.

Facing this problem cause the results as you may notice are Map since i am new in Java and I am so confused at this point.

Anyone can suggest from something to start of?

Updated:::
countIntInNumbers method as follows

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> countIntInNumbers(int[][] mat) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> intOccurences = new HashMap<>();
    for (int[] row : mat) {
        for (int intInRow : row) {
            Integer occurences = intOccurences.get(intInRow);
            if (occurences == null) { // first occurrence
                intOccurences.put(intInRow, 1);
            } else { // increment
                intOccurences.put(intInRow, occurences.intValue() + 1);
            }

        }

    }
    return intOccurences;
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `countIntInNumbers`?

Comment: *i want to print all numbers that their total is between 3 and 4*. A single number can't have a total other than itself. What are you trying to say? What would be the expected output in the above example? *i am so confused at this point.* So am I.

Comment: Post updated with the method;s code

Comment: Still not clear what you're trying to do now.

Comment: Ok ... the method countIntInNumbers is returning 2 Integer as result 1=17, 2=10, 3=16, etc etc.... I need to take those results and print the 1ts number to new tables depending the number after =.... Hope i was clear now :(

Comment: You use the words "print  ... to a separate table".  That makes no sense.  Printing usually means displaying.  Do you mean copying the numbers to a different table?

Comment: Explain the broader problem. What's the expected output going to look like? What are you tasked with solving?

Comment: @Rogue ,let me make ti clear for you all and really sorry for my bad English..
 my main problem is the following: 
1- the Method countInNumbers is providing me some results which you can see on the main post.
2- I need to save those results - then displaying THOSE results based to the number after the = ... !!!!!

**example** ...as you can see on the main post 1=17 , 4 = 17 and 16=17 .. so every number has a value... Need to display all the numbers with the same values in one table... same with any other numbers that having equal values..... Hope i was clear . Thank for patience.

Comment: Okay, so what you're looking to do is group the keys based on their respective values, and then display that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to separate the numbers on different table depending their total value. Example... I want to print all numbers that their total is between 3 and 4 to separate table than the other numbers.

We are not sure what you are asking here but if you mean that you want to display the numbers which have a total between 2 numbers then you could do something like:

```
private void printNumbers(Map<Integer, Integer> intOccurences, int minTotal, int maxTotal){
    boolean first = false;
    System.out.print("{");
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : intOccurences.entrySet()) {
        int total = entry.getValue();
        if (total >= minTotal && total <= maxTotal) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.print(entry.getKey() + "=" + total);
        }
    }
    System.out.print("}");
}
```

If you are taking about *copying* the values to a new map then maybe something like:

```
private Map<Integer, Integer> extractNumbers(Map<Integer, Integer> intOccurences,
       int minTotal, int maxTotal) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : intOccurences.entrySet()) {
        int total = entry.getValue();
        if (total >= minTotal && total <= maxTotal) {
            result.put(entry.getKey(), total);
        }
    }
    // not sure if you want to remove the ones from the original map
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Excactly this you mentioned "We are not sure what you are asking here but if you mean that you want to display the numbers which have a total between 2 numbers then you could do something like:"
Can you explain me now how to add the results of the 1st method in the one you just created in order to work?

Comment: What is the "1st method"?  You mean `countIntInNumbers(...)`.  You need to do that first and then once you have the totals, you can call the print or extract methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the value of a map just get it by key. Then since the values of the map are of wrapper Integer you can compare using ==, >=, <= since the Integer equals() method simply compares the int value it wraps with the other Integer's int value. In example:

```
 // Adding some test values to the map
 Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put(1, 5);
 map.put(2, 6);
 map.put(3, 5);

 // Get values by key map.get(key)
 // Compare values map.get(key) == map.get(key) or use >=, <=
 System.out.println(map.get(1) <= map.get(2)); // true
 System.out.println(map.get(1) == map.get(3)); // true
 System.out.println(map.get(1) >= map.get(2)); // false
```

In your countIntInNumbers it seems you are just returning and printing the map by using its toString() method. If I got you right you want to print the keys which values are between 3 and 4. In this case the values are Integer so there will not be any value between 3 and 4 other than the integers themselves.

Okay after seeing your edit, convert your raw matrix to a map and then search for the values you need, and put them into a new map. Something like this:

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> countIntInNumbers(int[][] mat) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> matConvertedToMap = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++)
    {
        matConvertedToMap.put(mat[i][0], mat[i][1]);
    }

    Map<Integer, Integer> intOccurences = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : matConvertedToMap.entrySet())
    {
        if(entry.getValue() ==  3 || entry.getValue() ==  4)
        {
            intOccurences.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    return intOccurences;
}
```

Not sure what the comparison really is and what you are expected to return but that should give you a general feeling of how to iterate through the map.

Comment: entry: map.entrySet()
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>

Comment: @Annu Take a look at my edit. I am still not sure if that is what you are trying to do. But as I said it should give you a good hint.

Comment: THank you very much you was really helpfull... i got in point... <3